# Persistance countdown on refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have one problem to solve and i am not a master in javascript, basically when is loaded my element id which will be in my code down to start a count down from 2hours minutes and seconds but i have links where on click refresh the page and is refreshing my counter i found full counter here is link:
 [JavaScript count down, add hours & minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262697/javascript-count-down-add-hours-minutes)

```
var count = 7200;
var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer() {
    count = count - 1;
    if (count == -1) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }

    var seconds = count % 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;
    hours %= 60;

    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours + " ora " + minutes + " minute" + seconds + " secunde ramase ";
}
```

I just want to make this counter to not reset on refresh.

Comment: @jack bashford is suggesting you use local storage which I feel it’s ok. You could also try cookies. You can set them to expire after 2 hours, then implement your counter base on the time difference.

Comment: And to be clear here, two different users can use the same computer to visit your app and you don’t wanna use the timer for the first user for the second. So you need to identify each timer with a valid ID or sort

Comment: Good question i will think about this one! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `localStorage`:

```
var count = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("count")) || 7200;

function timer() {
    //...
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours + " ora " + minutes + " minute" + seconds + " secunde ramase ";
    localStorage.setItem("count", count);
}
```

To redirect your page and clear `localStorage` when the timer hits `0`, add this code to your function:

```
function timer() {
    count = count - 1;
    if (count == 0) {
        localStorage.removeItem("count");
        window.location.href = "home.html";
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Bare in mind that localForage may be a better option if it needs to 99.99% persist over all devices. localStorage can sometimes get cleared on mobile devices.

Comment: That`s will not be a problem, but i have another question. In that `count == 0` i can set also my session 0? i have a session in php which is 1 and i want if `count == 0` to make that session = 0? it is possible?